# Oracle SQL to update fields (personal information fields) in a record by getting random data from another record

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update

I have a record with lots of rows containing personal information.
Table A

```
ID,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Emai,Phone,Address
```

I am trying to scrub the data using another dataset I created using randomuser.me api.
I have the data stored in another Table B

```
firstname,lastname,gender, phone, processed_flag
```

I want to update all the fields of Table A by getting random data from Table B and once I use that row from table B, I should update processed_flag as 'Y' so that I do not duplicate the information.

As a result all the data of Table A is scrubbed for security reasons in my non prod databases. Is this possible using Merge statements as I would like to update 10000s of rows. Any help is appreciated. Since there are no keys matching, I am not sure of the approach hence unable to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MERGE` statement with window functions as follows:

```
MERGE INTO TABLEA A
USING (SELECT BB.FIRSTNAME, BB.LASTNAME, BB.GENDER, BB.PHONE, AA.ID
          FROM ( SELECT ID,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ROWID ) AS RN
                   FROM TABLEA ) AA
          JOIN ( SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER, PHONE,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ROWID ) AS RN
                   FROM TABLEB WHERE PROCESSED_FLAG = 'N') BB
        ON AA.RN = BB.RN) B
ON (B.ID = A.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET A.FIRSTNAME = B.FIRSTNAME, 
           A.LASTNAME = B.LASTNAME, 
           A.GENDER = B.GENDER, 
           A.PHONE = B.PHONE;
```

You can then use the updated table A values, match with Table B value, and update the process flag.

Comment: I don't have an ID field in Table B , hence it has to be random row from table B used to update table A

Comment: I know, and I haven;t used any ID from tableB.. I have used row_number based on rowid which will give you randomness if you think it as a logic. and you can also use the RANDOM function

Comment: "I should update processed_flag as 'Y' so that I do not duplicate the information." How would you update the processed rows to have a flag of `Y` using this `MERGE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE rowid_list IS TABLE OF ROWID;
  
  updating_rows rowid_list;
  masking_rows  rowid_list;
  num_rows PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID
  BULK COLLECT INTO updating_rows
  FROM   TableA
  FOR UPDATE;
  
  num_rows := updating_rows.COUNT;
  
  UPDATE TableB
  SET   processed_flag = 'Y'
  WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT ROWID
    FROM   TableB
    WHERE  processed_flag = 'N'
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
    FETCH FIRST num_rows ROWS ONLY
  )
  RETURNING ROWID BULK COLLECT INTO masking_rows;
  
  IF num_rows > masking_rows.COUNT THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Not enough masking rows' );
  END IF;
  
  FORALL i IN 1 .. num_rows
    MERGE INTO TableA dst
    USING (
      SELECT t.*
      FROM   TableB t
      WHERE  ROWID = masking_rows(i)
    ) src
    ON ( dst.ROWID = updating_rows(i) )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET first_name = src.first_name,
          last_name  = src.last_name,
          gender     = src.gender,
          phone      = src.phone;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableA ( id, first_name, last_name, gender, phone ) AS
SELECT  1, 'Alice',   'Adams',  'F', '01111' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Barry',   'Baron',  'M', '02222' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Carol',   'Clark',  'F', '03333' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'Denis',   'Devlin', 'M', '04444' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Edward',  'Evans',  'M', '05555' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'Frances', 'Frank',  'F', '06666' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Gemma',   'Graham', 'F', '07777' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Harry',   'Harris', 'M', '08888' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'Imogen',  'Inman',  'F', '09999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Kira',    'Kirk',   'F', '01010' FROM DUAL;
```

and some (randomised) masking data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableB ( first_name, last_name, gender, phone, processed_flag ) AS
SELECT f.first_name,
       l.last_name,
       g.gender,
       LPAD( FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 1000 ) ), 4, '0' ),
       'N'
FROM   ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ) AS id,
                'First' || LEVEL AS first_name
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  20 ) f
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ) AS id,
                'Last' || LEVEL AS last_name
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  20 ) l
       ON ( f.id = l.id )
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT LEVEL AS id,
                CASE FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 3 ) )
                WHEN 1 THEN 'F'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'M'
                END AS gender
         FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20 ) g
       ON ( g.id = f.id )
```

Then the table is updated to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableA;
```

> ```
> ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | GENDER | PHONE
> -: | :--------- | :-------- | :----- | :----
>  1 | First19    | Last20    | M      | 0809 
>  2 | First5     | Last6     | M      | 0814 
>  3 | First16    | Last14    | M      | 0319 
>  4 | First12    | Last3     | M      | 0162 
>  5 | First3     | Last2     | F      | 0388 
>  6 | First2     | Last5     | F      | 0846 
>  7 | First8     | Last10    | M      | 0299 
>  8 | First13    | Last15    | M      | 0063 
>  9 | First18    | Last17    | F      | 0714 
> 10 | First14    | Last19    | F      | 0079
> ```

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

> ```
> FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | GENDER | PHONE | PROCESSED_FLAG
> :--------- | :-------- | :----- | :---- | :-------------
> First6     | Last4     | F      | 0687  | N             
> First9     | Last18    | F      | 0633  | N             
> First1     | Last9     | M      | 0405  | N             
> First10    | Last1     | F      | 0919  | N             
> First19    | Last20    | M      | 0809  | Y             
> First15    | Last12    | M      | 0321  | N             
> First5     | Last6     | M      | 0814  | Y             
> First4     | Last11    | F      | 0677  | N             
> First16    | Last14    | M      | 0319  | Y             
> First17    | Last8     | M      | 0192  | N             
> First11    | Last13    | M      | 0153  | N             
> First12    | Last3     | M      | 0162  | Y             
> First20    | Last7     | F      | 0931  | N             
> First3     | Last2     | F      | 0388  | Y             
> First2     | Last5     | F      | 0846  | Y             
> First7     | Last16    | F      | 0725  | N             
> First8     | Last10    | M      | 0299  | Y             
> First13    | Last15    | M      | 0063  | Y             
> First18    | Last17    | F      | 0714  | Y             
> First14    | Last19    | F      | 0079  | Y
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ddfc472acb8575223cc25b031851c83)*